# Is there any example of a network-based anti-virus system?

Tags: antivirus

Is there any example of network-based anti-virus system?

There are two types of anti-virus systems; one is **host-based**, and the other is **network-based**.

We often see host-based anti-virus systems（such as Kaspersky, but very rarely do we see network-based systems.

Are there any examples and explain the principles?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question?  Are you asking something that checking the traffics from the firewall level (Web application firewall) , or something that able to check network anomalies (Intrusion detection system) , or something beyond those? In facts, prominent brand AV also check strange network behavior on the host computer.

Comment: Once you change the terms to what I used in your question, this now becomes a simple google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=network+based+antivirus

Answer (score 2):

You don't provide enough context around your quote (from unknown source) but my guess is that this refers to systems, which don't only check for malware on the specific host but which are responsible for a network. Examples of this are antivirus used in mail or web gateways (and firewalls) which analyze the incoming (and sometimes outgoing) traffic (typically) at the perimeter. But also antivirus on file servers which check data on network file systems which can be accessed from all over the network.